# Replace encoded £ signs

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I'm displaying a list of products as read off of the RSS feed from an eBay shop.

http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/custommodsuk/_i.html?rt=nc&_rss=1&_rssstore=1

As you can see, they have encoded the 2nd pound sign on "Buy it now for only: £45.00"

So I've set about correcting this on the front end for users, and i'm really struggling to do a global replace on each product's HTML.

```
ebayItemsContainer.find('.listItem').each(function () {
                var itemHTML = $(this).html();
                var newHTML = itemHTML.replace(&#163;/gi, '£');
                $(this).html(newHTML)
            });
```

Even without the semi colon on the replace, it won't replace the encoded character with the actual character.

Also escaping the characters errors...

```
var newHTML = itemHTML.replace(\&\#163\;/gi, '£');
```

Can anybody help, I'm sure it's a fundamental issue?

Comment: Are you really leaving off the leading "/" character in the regular expression?

Comment: no forgot it for the example... had been playing around for a while. Wasn't the real error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is missing the `/` at the start, but also, the value is actually doubly-encoded as `&amp;#163;` (you can see this if you do view source).

```
itemHTML.replace(/&amp;#163;/gi, '£');
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it, I did have the preceeding / just forgot it for the example, while i was messing around.  It was the double encoding, good spot.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is missing the beginning:

`var newHTML = itemHTML.replace(/&amp;#163;/gi, '£');`

However I would just make it a string instead of a regex, seems easier to me:

`var newHTML = itemHTML.replace('&amp;#163;', '£');`

Note that the XML file has encoded the ampersand.

Comment: Passing a string as the first arg, as opposed to a RegExp (with pattern modifiers) will only replace the first occurance. A global replace is cited as a requirement in the question, although whether it is actually required or not is not clear from the example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply enclosing it in quotes?

`var newHTML = itemHTML.replace('&#163;', '£');`

...because, isn't it really just a string of text to replace?

Comment: Passing a string as the first arg, as opposed to a RegExp (with pattern modifiers) will only replace the first occurance. A global replace is cited as a requirement in the question, although whether it is actually required or not is not clear from the example.